# Transparent Activity left right margin

Tags: android, android-layout

Transparent activity is there in my app and I want to give left, right, top margin to this activity. For this I am using **WindowManager.LayoutParams**. But there I am not able to give Gravity top, right, left at a time. There is only two parameter x and y. If I want to set left, right and top then what I need to do.

Code:-

```
public class SelectedRecipient extends Activity {
private Context context;
private WindowManager.LayoutParams wmParams=null;
private ListView listView;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);



    System.out.println("*** SelectedRecipient ***");

    context = SelectedRecipient.this;

    WindowManager.LayoutParams wmParams = this.getWindow().getAttributes();

    wmParams.gravity = Gravity.TOP | Gravity.LEFT;
    wmParams.x = 50; // x position
    wmParams.y = 40; // y position

    ArrayList<String> aListNoOfSelection = new ArrayList<String>();
    aListNoOfSelection.add("Vinit");
    aListNoOfSelection.add("Vikash");
    aListNoOfSelection.add("Jonson");
    aListNoOfSelection.add("Nikolesh");
    ArrayAdapter<String> aAdapterNoOfSelection = new NoOfSelectionAdapter(context, 0, aListNoOfSelection);

    listView = new ListView(context);

    listView.setAdapter(aAdapterNoOfSelection);
    setContentView(listView);
}
}
```

I also tried this(which not wwork):-

```
LayoutParams layoutParams = new LayoutParams(FrameLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, FrameLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
layoutParams.setMargins(50, 0, 50, 0);
listView.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
```

[image]

Comment: Maybe you want to show an activity with dialog theme.

Answer (score 0):

You probably want to use a dialog theme like answered above, if so... 
put `android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Dialog"` inside your AndroidManifest.xml

or by calling: `setTheme(android.R.style.Theme_Dialog);` before calling `setContentView();` in your `onCreate()`

if not you can use something like:

```
ViewGroup.MarginLayoutParams wmParams = new ViewGroup.MarginLayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
wmParams.setMargins((int left),(int top),(int right),(int bottom));
```

or `wmParams.bottomMargin` , `wmParams.leftMargin` , `wmParams.rightMargin` , `wmParams.topMargin`

Comment: when I mentioning android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Dialog" in manifest then it also show title and to remove when I use requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
then aliment completely destroy.

Comment: Where did you place that line `requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);` ?

Comment: It should be right after `super.onCreate()` and before `setContentView();`